# how can i install npm earliest version

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/refilwe/.npm/\_cacache/content-v2/sha512/2c/35
npm ERR! errno EEXIST
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/log-symbols: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/refilwe/.npm/\_cacache/content-v2/sha512/2c/35'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/refilwe/.npm/\_cacache/content-v2/sha512/2c/35
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/refilwe/.npm/\_logs/2023-07-06T08_28_27_953Z-debug-0.log

pc221:\~ refilwe$ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Why are your talking about the "earliest version" ? It has nothing to do with your issue. Can you give more context ? It looks like you don't have enough rights on your machine and/or have proxy issue.

Answer (score 1):

can you please specify which package you want to install or you just want to install cli with specific version can use this

`npm install -g @angular/cli@<version>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).